# How to fix "Cannot open load file" in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, startup

I have Gnuplot 4.6.6-2, and have been working with it a lot for the past couple of weeks.  All has been well.

My program file is called pl.gp and is really simple.  It has worked fine until now.  For whatever reason this is happening:

```
gnuplot> load "pl.gp"
         Unable to load file 'pl.gp'
         util.c: No such file or directory.
```

I removed gnuplot and gnuplot-x11 then reinstalled them, but the problem persists.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you are in the Gnuplot command line, does `pwd` give the expected directory?

Comment: You solved it, @maji.  I was in a hurry when opening terminal windows and had neglected going down into my subdirectory in the one where I was running gnuplot.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @maji thank you.  btw, this site is telling me I am in danged of being blocked from asking any more questions because nobody upvoted this question I asked when I was just getting started.  From where I stand it was very productive - you solved it for me..  I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a bash script in my home directory to make sure I don't do this again.  it is named gp:

```
cd /home/pi/python
gnuplot
```

Of course, had to do this to make it work:

```
chmod +x gp
```

To run it, in a new window I just type :

```
./gp
```

Also made a copy in the python directory so it will work in either location - because I used a full-qualified directory name.

I suppose I could copy it to /usr/sbin so all I would have to type is

```
 gp
```

from anywhere to end up in the right place with gnuplot..

Comment: I can understand that.  In this case I wasn't lazy per se, but the prompt gave me no indication I was in the wrong directory.  I just assumed it would work in a new terminal window like the one right before it.  Now THAT is a n00b mistake if there ever was one.  --  I've solved this by creating a script in my home directory that is called gp which puts me into the correct directory and starts gnuplot by simply typing ./gp -- I even put a copy of it in the target directory and because it uses a fully-qualified directory name in the cd command it still works even if I am already there.  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about that - quite a few of my questions were for problems caused by really trivial mistakes. However readers can mostly tell what sort of effort was made, and receiving a DV does not mean you did not make an effort. Some DVs are a bit random!

Comment: By the way, I have rolled back your question edit, sorry - we don't put any answer material in questions. You can merge it into your answer if you wish. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough.   I think the answer covers it pretty well now.  And yes, I did end up putting gp in /usr/sbin so even if I was out on my USB media device and want to get back to where I can plot some of the incoming data it is two letters then enter to get there.  TNX agn.

Comment: Hey, you can delete this and your answer once I read it, but let me ask you this.   What should I do about that deleted question?  it was about setting up tightVNC foolishly following the advice to use Powershell to install it in parts.  That was dumb.  Instead, when I ran their normal install package it did all the heavy lifting for me.  So now I am left with a deleted, closed, question that will never have any value for anyone.  And I am sure others have already discussed successful installs of TightVNC on PCs.  So I really want it to just go away.  I don't think repurposing it can help.

Comment: Mmm, not sure. Search [this community site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), and if that question has not already been asked, ask it there.

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

@Maji posted a comment which made me realize my mistake. I was in the wrong directory in one of the terminal windows.

Comment: Thank you, @halfer.  Better on-screen info would have helped (like showing the cwd in the prompt, or the full path in the error message), but in the end it was a hardware problem:  The nut between the chair and the keyboard.  ;-)

Comment: Great, thanks @SDsolar. Note that we do not use [solved] title edits here, the acceptance system is sufficient.

Comment: Got it.  I asked this one when I was new.  Maybe that is why I have zero votes and the system is warning me that I am in danger of not being allowed to ask any more?  From where I sit, this was great - I got the answer I needed.  The computers (or moderators) apparently don't take that into account.

Comment: On this question you got one +1 and one -1, and anyone over a minimal rep may have given you the downvote. If they don't say why they did, we cannot know for sure. Since you have no questions that have fallen below zero, I would guess you have deleted questions that are below zero. You could either repair one/some of these and then undelete in the hope of getting upvotes, or you could ask new questions which are detailed, thorough and feature code.

Comment: Ah.  Thank you, @halfer.  I am not exactly a n00b anymore, and I am sure I did exactly that, and might improve on deleted questions.  Would you be so kind as to tell me how to find them?  Thanks in advance.  -- -- -- -- (I have a new question but don't want banned - I get data of 3 columns, two temps then their difference -  Need to know how I can make the plot command treat the difference variable as a constant if it is >10 - This is a fan controller and I'd like it to draw a filled box showing the fan is on, but don't want to draw the variable showing the difference in temps itself)

Comment: @SDsolar: try clicking on the Questions tab in your profile, then clicking the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom. Meanwhile if you want to post a draft of your new question onto a Gist or a Pastie and send me a link in a comment, I can offer some feedback before you post it to SO.

Comment: OK, so I found the deleted question and it had been closed for being off-topic.  I disagree completely but you can't fight city hall, so that's why I deleted it.